# Aligning annotated text with colorbar label text

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'd like to find a way to make an annotation that automatically aligns with the label text of a colorbar. Take this example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5,10))
data = np.arange(1000, 0, -10).reshape(10, 10)
im = ax.imshow(data, cmap='Blues')
clb = plt.colorbar(im, shrink=0.4)
clb.ax.annotate('text', xy=(1, -0.075), xycoords='axes fraction')
```

[image]

I want to have the last t of "text" to be on the same x coordinate as the last 0 of 1000 in the colorbar label. I can do so manually by adjusting the xy parameter in annotate, but I have to do this for many graphs and would like to find a way to get the parameter from somewhere automatically.

How can I get the maximum x coordinate of the text labes and annotate in a way where the annotation ends on that coordinate? Could someone point me in the right direction? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the labels are left-aligned, but you want to align your additional text according to the *end* of that label, I fear there is no other choice than to find out the coordinates from the drawn figure and place the label accordingly.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import transforms
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5,4))
data = np.arange(1000, 0, -10).reshape(10, 10)
im = ax.imshow(data, cmap='Blues')
cbar = plt.colorbar(im)


# draw figure first to be able to retrieve coordinates
fig.canvas.draw()
# get the bounding box of the last label
bbox = cbar.ax.get_yticklabels()[-1].get_window_extent()
# calculate pixels back to axes coords
labx,_ = cbar.ax.transAxes.inverted().transform([bbox.x1,0]) 
ax.annotate('text', xy=(labx, -0.075), xycoords=cbar.ax.transAxes,
                 ha = "right")

plt.show()
```

[image]

Note that this approach will fail once you change the figure size afterwards or change the layout in any other way. It should hence always come last in your code.

Comment: Actually, I can't seem to replicate the figure. Somehow the annotation doesn't show up, even though I run your exact code. Could you help again?

Comment: I suppose you are running this in a jupyter notebook and hence do not see the annotation? In that case adding `%config InlineBackend.print_figure_kwargs = {'bbox_inches':None}` would help. But that's of course a little hacky.

Comment: I tried running it in spyder and jupyter notebook and neither showed the annotation. I have no idea what the line does, but this indeed makes it appear in Jupyter. Any idea on spyder?

Comment: Spyder is an IDE; it allows a variety of options to run code. I'm using spyder as well and it works for me. But if you e.g. use the IPython console to run your code the same line from above should help as well.

Comment: I see. I usually run my code in the IPython console and there it doesn't show up (your line doesn't do anything there). Once I used the python console, it does (even without the line). Weird. Thanks a lot!

Comment: To explain: the line above will configure IPython, not to crop the figure, which it does by default. So [it would work, even in Spyder with IPython](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ALPzY.png). But I'm going to investigate further why that line is even needed, might be a bug.

Comment: I updated the solution. This should now work in jupyter, IPython and as script.

Comment: One more follow up question: how would I have to adjust the line `labx,_ = cbar.ax.transAxes.inverted().transform([bbox.x1,0])` if I had a y value? Say if I wanted to annotate on the same height as one of the tick labels? Would be fantastic, if you could find the time to answer.

Comment: You replace the `0` by the coordinate from the bbox and use the second unpacked variable as y coordinate for the text.

Comment: I tried this but it didn't seem to work. Probably I made a mistake somewhere. Thanks!